# How do I convert a Char into a Keycode in .Net?

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to convert a string into a series of Keycodes, so that I can then send them via PostMessage to a control.  I need to simulate actual keyboard input, and I'm wondering if a massive switch statement is the only way to convert a character into the correct keycode, or if there's a simpler method.

====

Got my solution - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646329(VS.85).aspx

VkKeyScan will return the correct keycode for any character.

(And yes, I wouldn't do this in general, but when doing automated testing, and making sure that keyboard presses are responded to correctly, it works reliably enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my solution - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646329(VS.85).aspx

VkKeyScan will return the correct keycode for any character.

(And yes, I wouldn't do this in general, but when doing automated testing, and making sure that keyboard presses are responded to correctly, it works reliably enough).

Answer (score 2):

Raymond says this is a bad idea.

http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx

Comment: And Raymond even suggests a better technique.

Answer (score 0):

For A-z 1-9 you could try build the char into a keycode string `string.Format("KEY_KEY_{0}", char.ToString())` then use Enum.Parse to extract the Enum value, but it's a bit of a cludge

Or look at [How to convert uint keycode to Keys enum](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_23092844.html) on expert sexchange, and just work around the tricky cases.

I agree a switch statement is kinda awful

Answer (score 0):

A much more reliable wait to send a string of keystrokes to a window is to use the SendKeys class

```
 System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys("This is a test");
 System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys("This is sends CTRL+J ^j");
```

This will be more predictable and should save you some time.

Comment: Unfortunately it only works if your window will definitely have the focus.  Which mine won't.